# Test controller with promises with jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, controller, jasmine

I'm writing a test for a controller that uses a service.
This is the controller:

```
  $scope.loadData = function(){
UserDataService.query({
        user_id: $routeParams.user_id }
).$promise.then (function (data) {
    $scope.labels = data.label;
    $scope.data = data.data;
    $.each($scope.data, function (key, value) {
        $scope.original_keys.push(key);
        $scope.original_data.push(value);
    });
},
function (error) {
    $location.path("/404");

});
};
$scope.loadData();
```

And this is the service:

```
  angular.module('services')
.factory('UserDataService', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
var hostURL = 'http://localhost:9000';

    return $resource( hostURL + '/api/users/:user_id',
        {user_id: '@user_id'}, {
            'query': {method: 'GET'}

        });

}]);
```

This is the test I've wrote:

```
ddescribe('UsersCtrl - Mattia Version', function () {

var scope, location, fakeDataService, fakeEditService, routeParams, UsersCtrl;
var getDeferred;
var data={label:["a","b"]};
beforeEach(function() {
    module('maaperture');
});

beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function( $rootScope, $location, $routeParams, $controller, $q) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    location = $location;
    routeParams = $routeParams;
    fakeDataService = {
        query: function() {return $http().then();}
    };

    getDeferred = $q.defer();
    getDeferred.resolve(data);

    spyOn(fakeDataService, 'query').andReturn(getDeferred);


    UsersCtrl = $controller('UsersCtrl', {
        '$scope': scope,
        '$location': location,
        'UserDataService': fakeDataService,
        'UserEditService': fakeEditService,
        '$routeParams': routeParams
    });
}));

it('should call stuff', function () {
    expect(fakeDataService.query).toHaveBeenCalled();
});

it('should set some data on the scope when successful', function () {
    scope.loadData();
    scope.$apply();
    scope.$digest();
    expect(fakeDataService.get).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(scope.data).toEqual(getResponse.data);
});
```

It should be correct as I've followed a lot of guides, but I keep getting

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

Everytime I run it.
I run my test with karma and jasmine. Can't really figure out why I get this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because deferred object doesn't have $promise property. Using $httpBackend is better way.

Try this:

```
describe('UsersCtrl - Mattia Version', function () {

  var scope, routeParams, UsersCtrl;
  var $httpBackend;

  var data = {label: ["a", "b"]};

  beforeEach(module('maaperture', 'services', 'ngResource', 'ngRoute'));

  beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function ($rootScope, $routeParams, $controller, _$httpBackend_) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    routeParams = $routeParams;
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;

    routeParams.user_id = 1;

    UsersCtrl = $controller('UsersCtrl', {
      '$scope': scope,
      '$routeParams': routeParams
    });
  }));

  it('should set some data on the scope when successful', function () {
    // Given
    $httpBackend.whenGET('http://localhost:9000/api/users/' + routeParams.user_id).respond(200, data);

    // When
    scope.loadData();
    $httpBackend.flush();

    // Then
    expect(scope.data).toEqual(data.data);
  });
});
```

Services :

```
angular.module('services', [])
  .factory('UserDataService', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    var hostURL = 'http://localhost:9000';

    return $resource(hostURL + '/api/users/:user_id',
      {user_id: '@user_id'}, {
        'query': {method: 'GET'}
      });
  }]);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried your solution but it gives me this error:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: UserDataServiceProvider <- UserDataService
Have I forgotten something?

Comment: you should inject the module which has UserDataService into beforeEach. 
--> 
  beforeEach(module('maaperture', 'your module!', 'ngResource', 'ngRoute'));

Comment: I am loading it, here : beforeEach(module('maaperture','services', 'ngResource', 'ngRoute'));
Services is the module with UserDataService

Comment: Nevermind, it was my problem! works like a charm, thank you a lot